# How to convert foreach to Linq

Tags: linq

I am not sure how to convert this simple foreach to linq.

It seems pretty easy, but I keep getting compile errors?

```
            var createAccount = from TransactionDetail td in transactionDetails
                    Where
                          td.ResponseType == ResponseType.SUCCESS AND
                          td.RequestType == RequestType.CREATE_ACCOUNT 
                     SELECT true;

            /* trying to convert this */


            bool createAccount = true;
            foreach(TransactionDetail td in transactionDetails  )
            {
                if (td.RequestType == RequestType.CREATE_ACCOUNT)
                {
                    if (td.ResponseType == ResponseType.SUCCESS)
                    {
                        createAccount = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you want is a boolean result, you don't need `where` or `select`. Use the  `Any` method:

```
bool createAccount = !transactionDetails.Any(
    td => td.RequestType == ... && td.ResponseType == ...);
```

Comment: It should be `!transactionDetails.Any(...);`

Comment: `.Any()` is specifically designed for this purpose.  When using `.Any(...)`, LINQ will use the quickest method it has to determine if any such item meets that criteria.  This is faster (or at least as fast) as other methods like a foreach, using `.Count()` or anything else.

Comment: Essentially it would be the same as that `foreach`, except with an added `break`.